# How to improve the foreach perfomence In php

Tags: php

I have two array

1) $pcinput_array have 3000 records
2) $compare_array have 3.5 lax records (depends upon my requirement it will increasing)

```
foreach($compare_array as $key => $val){

$bRutgers = convertResult($val['results'],$val['snp']); //this array have 96 records

foreach($pcinput_array  as $inkey => $inval){
       $aRutgers = convertResult($inval['results'],$inval['snp']); //this array have 96 records

       $result_array = array_intersect_assoc($aRutger,$bRutger);        
       $total = count($result_array);
       if($totalMatched >= $this->allotherRutgersMatch)
       {
        $status = true;

       }

       if($status)
       {
            $result['status'] = '0';
            $pass[] = $val['ruid'];
       }
       else
       {
            $fail[] = $val['ruid'];
       }   

}

}


public function convertResult($value,$key)
    {
        $values = str_split($value);
        $keys = explode(',',$key);
        //$results = $this->safeArrayCombine($keys, $values);
        $results = array_combine($keys,$values);
        return $results;
    }
```

While run this coding my php server freezing and also its taking 3 to 4 hour. I need improve the performance. How to improve the performance. Please help me. I have struggle last two week.

Thanks,
Sivanesan.v

Comment: if ($status) is useless if you don't use $status variable. you will win a var declaration + a var affectation + a var check

Comment: This is a relatively small piece of code. If you're sure that the problem is contained here then there's probably little you can do without changing your approach. Without a good idea of what this is trying to do (i.e some sample input and output data) I doubt anyone will be able to help much.

Comment: Have you done any benchmark ? How long does it take ?

Comment: There are tricks you can use to speed up loops but they all will have relatively little impact.  Your best bet is simply reduce the amount of data you're trying to process in one go.